# My image is broken when im displaying using php

Tags: php, html

When im displaying the image of restaurant but the image is broken.can anyone help me to solve or find out the problem?i tried to googling or looking tutorial yet i found there are several way to store image which is either storing the file path to database or storing the image to database,in my case is storing the file path to database.
this is the data in my database.the image is type is blob.[image]
[image]

this is my html code for displaying

```
<?php
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurant";
            $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            <tr>
                        <td>{$row['ID']}</td>
                        <td>";echo "<img src='".$row['Logo']."' />";echo "</td>
                        <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['ContactNumber']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['Address']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['CuisineType']}</td> 
                        <td>{$row['SupportArea']}</td> 
            </tr>\n";
            }
?>
```

this is php code for adding restaurant

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
            //define other variables with submitted values from $_POST
            $name = $_POST['restaurant_name'];
            $contactnum = $_POST['restaurant_contactnum'];
            $address = $_POST['restaurant_address'];
            $cuisinetype = $_POST['cuisinetype'];
            $checkbox1 = $_POST['area'];


            $allowedExts = array("png","jpg","jpeg"); /* ACCEPTED FILE FORMAT */
            $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); /* GET THE FILE EXTENSION */
            $extension = strtolower($extension); /* LOWER THE STRINGS OF THE EXTENSION */

            $chk=""; 
            foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1) 
            { 
            $chk.= $chk1.","; 
            }


         if(in_array($extension,$allowedExts)){ /* IF FILE IS INDEED AN IMAGE */

            $photo="restaurantlogo/" . $_FILES["restaurant_logo"]["name"];
            }

                //insert user data into database
                $sql = "INSERT INTO restaurant (Logo, Name, Password, ContactNumber, Address, CuisineType, SupportArea ) VALUES ('$photo', '$name', '$password', '$contactnum', '$address', '$cuisinetype','$chk')";

            $insert = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                //check if mysql query is successful
                if ($sql){
                    //redirect the user to welcome.php
                    header("Location: ../restaurant-add.php");
                }
```

Comment: try `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Logo']).'"/>';`

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you. You need to do a lot more research and break the problem down into the core elements. Concentrate just on the `<img src` line - what is the value of src? What is the error you get? What if you hard code the location to the image? Try displaying the image manually, and adding small amounts of code bit by bit until the problem arises.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `PHP` output. You were missing `echo` at multiple places and I exchanged the `"` for `'` so the `HTML <img>'s` `src` tag is wrapped in `" "`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
<?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurant";
      $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      {
         echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['ID'].'</td>
            <td><img src="'.$row['Logo'].'" /></td>
            <td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['ContactNumber'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['Address'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['CuisineType'].'</td> 
            <td>'.$row['SupportArea'].'</td> 
        </tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ok, can you please post the output of this:  `echo $row['Logo'];` so I can see the output of the variable. The image path might be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Click F12 to open inspect element, check if you are getting valid src path for image.

If it is valid, try to open in in new tab and see if it appears there. Clearly you will find your error there

Comment: OP is storing image in `DB` not storing in folder.

Comment: what is the result for inspect element?

Comment: @urfusion I think he is storing image path to the database.

Comment: @Ivan86 : Yep, I just check.

Comment: <img src="C:xampp&#9;mpphpF1E8.tmp">  is path for the image,when i open in a new tab and i got this message "Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."

Comment: C:xamppmpphp9299.tmp Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)